# Projection matrix sign confusion (edited title)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Down I have edited my question.
 I am projecting Wxyz to image(u,v) and getting some wrong result. I can't figure out where is mistake. Please help some one to figure out.

Given:

```
Wxyzz =
       386.06       197.02      -1821.8            1
       407.32         -108      -1859.1            1
       4.9764       290.92      -1531.2            1
       103.39      -233.07      -1643.2            1
        189.7       320.19      -1667.9            1
       76.279        147.9      -1597.2            1
       47.798      -319.51      -1605.8            1
       164.74       -223.1      -1688.6            1
       482.06      -251.66      -1921.2            1
       226.42      -213.27      -1733.6            1
```

```
Wxyz=Wxyz' %';
%# intrinsic

fu = 2640; fv =2640; uo= 1514; vo = 994;

A= [ fu 0  uo 0
      0  fv  vo 0
      0  0  1    0
      0 0   0   1];

Exterior=[-6.6861,12.6118,-8.0660,[-0.4467,-0.3168,0.2380]*pi/180];%# deg 2 rad
%#data
X0=Exterior(1);
Y0=Exterior(2);
Z0=Exterior(3);
ax=Exterior(4);
by=Exterior(5);
cz=Exterior(6);
%#Rotation in X

 Rx = [1  0        0
        0  cos(ax)  -sin(ax)
        0  sin(ax)  cos(ax)];


%#Rotation in Y    
Ry = [cos(by)  0  sin(by)
        0        1  0
        -sin(by) 0  cos(by)];


%#Rotation in Z        
Rz = [cos(cz) -sin(cz) 0
        sin(cz) cos(cz)  0
        0       0        1];
R=Rx*Ry*Rz;

T=[X0;Y0;Z0];
Extrinsic= R';
Extrinsic(:,4) = -(R')* (T);
Extrinsic(4,:)   =  [0 0 0 1]


PImage =  A* Extrinsic* Wxyz;  

%#Obtain the X's
PImage(1 ,:) = PImage(1 ,:) ./ PImage(3 ,:);
%#Obtain the Y's
PImage(2 ,:) = PImage(2 ,:) ./ PImage(3 ,:);
```

I am getting

```
PImage =

       955.93       707.43      -1814.4            1
       939.75       1147.6      -1854.2            1
       1506.3       490.36        -1521            1
       1352.7       1370.2      -1637.6            1
       1213.9       485.04      -1658.4            1
       1389.7       749.08      -1588.5            1
       1440.9       1521.6      -1600.6            1
       1261.2       1344.2      -1683.2            1
       857.22         1340      -1917.8            1
       1173.9       1319.9      -1728.5            1
```

I supposed to get( real 2 D points)

```
img =

       2072.8       706.69
       2088.9       1146.9
       1522.6        489.6
       1676.1       1369.5
       1814.9        484.3
       1639.2       748.35
       1587.9       1520.9
       1767.6       1343.5
       2171.4       1339.3
       1854.9       1319.2
```

If I use
 A= [ -fu 0  uo 0
          0  fv  vo 0
          0  0  1    0
          0 0   0   1];
I get corect answer.
I can't figure out where is mistake in rotation or translation; Why Pimage(:,1) is not identical with img(:,1).
Any help will be grateful.

Comment: You are not getting an error. You are just getting the incorrect results. Please format the code with 4 spaces indent, and edit the question. If you are getting an error, then what is the error message?

Comment: I can see many people are confused by your poor explanation. A is the camera calibration matrix (AKA intrinsics); Wxyzz are 3-D homogeneous co-ordinates; Exterior is some initial pose configuration. Perhaps you can reformulate your code with some more explanation so we don't have to guess these things.

Comment: Is the first line, `Wxyz=Wxyz' %';`, a typo? It doesn't look like MATLAB to me.

Answer (score 1):

You've done the rotation, and you've done the transformation. 
What you need to do is the projection! Now I don't know what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but I don't see a projection matrix anywhere. So that's the first thing you need to fix.

Remember that doing a projection is a R4 -> R4 operation. If you're trying to get an R2 vector, you're trying to do something else (more).

see more at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29).

if you really want to learn the details, you can watch and learn courtesy of [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTcSBB3uVP0)

Comment: @shahbaba I don't understand what a lot of your values are. I can't spend inordinate amount of time guessing what's in your head. You need to be more specific on what you're trying to do. I need to understand what you're trying to accomplish as you're doing more then just projecting... What is `A`, what is `fu` and `fv`, where do you define the `(u,v)` subspace? is `img`and/or PImage 2-d or 4-d (as you can't just jump from one to another without costs, more operations)